# XCode 6.0 does not open on OS X 10.9.4

Tags: xcode, macos

I just downloaded XCode_6_beta_6.dmg from the official apple website. However, when prompted to drag the installation to the application folder, it just unarchived the installation but does not install XCode_6_beta_6. When i try to open xcode_6_beta_6 from the applications folder, the new xcode6 beta icon just keeps popping in the application dock and does nothing. How do i overcome this situation so that the new xcode6 beta is installed on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some weird reason, apple does not trust this installation and hence does not continue.

Please follow the below instructions to continue with the installation.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open Security and Privacy
3. Unlock the settings screen if it is not already unlocked.
4. select "Anywhere" from the "Allow apps downloaded from:" section.
5. lock and close the preferences screen.

Your installation shall start in a moment!!

Answer (score 0):

Also happened to me. Used Deepak's fix but had an additional strange problem where the Icon would still stay bouncing in the dock. Be patient & wait (for me it took a good 10 minutes!) for a dialogue box to eventually appear saying 'This is an application downloaded from the internet, do you want to open?' Obviously click 'Open'. Odd, considering it's Apple's own app.